# Differences between system function "ping" and Net::Ping module in perl?

Tags: perl

As I know there are two ways to find the pingable ip through the perl, which are

```
 1. Using system Ping Command.
 2. Using Net::Ping Module.
```

I tried to invoke the pingable state of the IP through the above two techniques.

I am facing a problem in those methods, that is system ping command is returning true for one IP. But, the Net::Ping Module is returning false for the same IP.

I don't know which one is correct. Anyone please advice me to prefer the right way to find a pingable IP. I have written the sample code snippet below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Net::Ping;

my $ip_address = $ARGV[0];
chomp($ip_address);

#Using Net::Ping Module

my $p = Net::Ping->new();


if ( $p->ping($ip_address) ) {
    print "Step - 1: Success!\n";
}
else {
    print "Step - 1: Fail!\n";
}


#Using System Command

$retval=system("ping -c 2 $ip_address");

if ($retval==0) {
    print "Step - 2: Success!\n";
} else {
    print "Step - 2: Fail!\n";
}

print "\n\n\ Step2: $retval\n\n";
```

For some IP address system command is returning success and Net::Ping is returning fail. Is any difference between those two methods?

Thanks,
Madhan

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: The code will execute in Unix server.

Answer (score 5):

One difference is that most low-level implementations of `ping` use ICMP packets, whereas [**`Net::Ping`**](http://search.cpan.org/~smpeters/Net-Ping-2.36/lib/Net/Ping.pm#Net%3a%3aPing-%3Enew%28%5B%24proto_%5B,_%24def_timeout_%5B,_%24bytes_%5B,_%24device_%5B,_%24tos_%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%29;) notes that TCP is the default. It also sends, by default to the echo port (7) which may be blocked on a particular machine. If you want to send ICMP packets, you have to specify ICMP as the first argument in the constructor.

Since you're using the defaults, I would say that those are the main differences. Also, ICMP does not have "ports", whereas TCP obviously *does*.

I like the explanation for `Net::Ping`'s using TCP though. `Net::Ping`--for servers it works with--gives you a better idea of which servers are up and responsive, rather than just attached to a network and can bounce ICMP packets.

However, if you just want what you have with your system `ping`, the doco points out that you can use the keyword `'external'` as the "protocol" to invoke the system `ping` command.

Comment: In my network windows and Unix systems are there. I need to change some dynamic IP to Manual. For that I need to find the pingable IP in a network. In that case only I am facing the issue as mentioned in my quetsion.. While using Net::Ping its unable to ping the windows IP in a network... Why?

Comment: @Madhan, see my last paragraph.